# Using dynamic programming with n-step ahead predictors

Tags: time-series, control-theory

Say I want to find the optimal control strategy involving a (partially) predictable stochastic process.

My predictor is autocorrelated with white noise innovations:
$$ p_t = \alpha p_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$

Using $p_t$, I am able to predict my stochastic process $r_t$ up to $n$ steps ahead:
$$ \mathrm{E}[r_{t+i}] = f_i(p_t) \hspace{1em} \forall i \in {1,...,n} $$

The optimal control problem I wish to solve is
$$ \max_{q_1, ..., q_T} \sum_{t=1}^T \mathrm{E} \left[ r_t \sum_{\tau=1}^t q_\tau - \lambda |q_t| \right] 
\\ s.t. \left| \sum_{t=1}^s q_t \right| <= L \hspace{1em} \forall s \in 1,...,T
$$
(To make it concrete, $r_t$ can be the returns on an investment, $p_t$ is some informative indicator, $q_t$ is the trade amount, $\lambda$ is the transaction cost per share, $L$ is the position limit, and the objective maximizes the trading P&L minus the transaction costs.)

Based on my limited understanding of dynamic programming, I believe I need to transform my problem so that rather than predicting $r_t$ n steps ahead, I am instead making repeated 1-step ahead predictions of future values of $p_t$ and using that to predict $r_t$.

My question is whether the transformation is necessary and whether there is a better way to just use my longer term predictions, $f_i(p_t)$, directly.